# JSF Managed beans do not appear in JSF pages

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I am developing a JSF application with JPA which currently having 76 managed beans in Netbeans. They were added with 
    @ManagedBean
    @SessionScopedWhen
annotations and not added to configuration files.
I want to add more managed beans, but the newly added beans are not appearing in JSF pages.
I am adding new Managed beans with Netbeans, by right clicking the package and selecting New > JSF Managed bean. Even refractory coping existing beans with a different name, no change.

For example, a newly added bean is displayed below.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package gov.sp.health.bean;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

/**
 *
 * @author buddhika
 */
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class TemBean {

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of TemBean
     */
    public TemBean() {
    }

    public String toIndex(){
        return "index";
    }

}
```

What is the cause for the error?

Answer (score 0):

I restarted Netbeans, everything fine, but don't know why?